# === in javascript and response returned from php ajax file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, type-coercion

I use jQuery for sending a value in PHP file via `$.post`.

```
$.post("ajax/comment_delete.php", { 
    comment_id: comment_id
}, function(response){/
    if (response == true) {
        tr.fadeOut(500, function() {
            tr.remove();
        })
    }
})//$.post
```

In PHP file I have:

```
if (isset($_POST['comment_id'])) {
    $comment_id = (int)$_POST['comment_id'];
    $comment = comment::find_by_id($comment_id);
    if (is_object($comment)) {
        echo $comment->delete();
    }
}
```

Everything works correctly, except when I use `response===true` it didn't work. My delete method returns `true` if the comment was deleted. When I `alert` the response, it shows `1`; is it normal for `1===true` to be false? Or is something wrong?

Comment: `console.log("1"==true); console.log("1"===true);` Type cohersion

Comment: ^ This. `===` checks for exact match, so you're basically saying if response is a boolean value of true, which it will never be. `==` while check if response is [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) or not:

Comment: @neilsimp checks for exact match, so you're basically saying if response is a boolean value of true, which it will never be.why? php send true as 1?

Comment: and im in doubt use == cause it may php send error string and strings count as true

Comment: @peyman You just said php sends true as 1, in JavaScript `"1"` isn't the same as `true` because thier different types. If PHP sends `"1"` as true why not check `response === "1"`

Comment: @peyman: In that case don't rely on simple true/false, but rather have the server-side code send a more structured response object.  That object can contain result codes, error messages, etc.  Currently your client-side code is basically just checking if it received a response at all and assuming success.

Comment: @David how send response object? and how hande it?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek You just said php sends true as 1, no I asked send true as 1 or not?

Answer (score 5):

> is it normal? or is something wrong?

It's normal.

The server-side code is emitting the value `"1"` (or `1`?  doesn't really matter for the purposes of this comparison), and whether or not that's what you *want* your server-side code to emit is another matter entirely.  But as long as that *is* what it's emitting, the JavaScript is behaving normally here.

["1" is "truthy" in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).  What this means is that `"1"` can be considered `true` for basic comparison with a boolean.  However, `"1"` isn't the same *type* as `true`, so the stricter comparison (===) isn't satisfied.

In short:

- `"1" == true` -> yes
- `"1" === true` -> no

Comment: so if error string emit from php file, it gone be true, isn't?

Comment: @peyman: Well, yes.  Any non-empty string is considered "true" for basic comparison with a boolean.  All your client-side code does right now is check if any non-empty response was received.  If you want to convey more information than that, don't rely on a simply boolean.  For errors, use HTTP error codes and include any messages in a more structured object in the response.  Then your client-side code can check for those things.